# Add CSS if Page URL equals <a> link on page not working when #anchor-tags are present

Tags: jquery, css, anchor, window.location

I have the following code that looks to see if the page URL is the same as a <a> "href"  of an item on the page and if it is it adds a CSS class to that <a> tag

```
  $(document).ready(function($){
      var pgurl = window.location.href;
      $("div.scrollmenu.restyled span").each(function(){
           if($(this).find('a').attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).find('a').attr("href") == '' )
            $(this).addClass("active");
      })
  });
```

This works brilliantly but I have anchors within some of the pages and this stops it from applying the CSS class to the item.

For instance domain.com/page-name/ adds the CSS class but domain.com/page-name/#named-anchor doesn't.

I guess I need to change my code so that it looks to see if the <a> "href" tag is contained within the page URL rather than matching exactly.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith (you can also use `indexOf` instead, if you need this to work in IE as well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `var pgurl` = `window.location.origin` + `window.location.pathname` .

It will give you the page URL not counting the hashes (#).